# Give a deduction showing that ∃x∀yRxy syntactically implies ∀y∃xRxy

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I know it's true but I have no idea how to write the deduction as there is no ∃ elimination rule that I know of. Am I supposed to use some kind of substitution?

Comment: Like you say, you need rules ... are you working with a specific proof system?

Comment: @Bram28 I don't think so. The rules are in pages 137-138 of this book: https://mileti.math.grinnell.edu/MathematicalLogic.pdf

Comment: Oh! So the rules are right there: two Existential rules and two Universal rules… you’ll probably need all 4

Comment: How am I supposed to remove the ∃x though?

Comment: Follow the rule of $\exists\mathsf P$.$$\dfrac{\mathcal S, \varphi^c_x\vdash \psi}{\mathcal S, \exists x~\varphi\vdash \psi}{\small\text{  where $c$ is not free in $\mathcal S, \exists x~\varphi, \psi$ and is a valid substituent for $x$ in $\varphi$}}$$ So $\small\dfrac{\dfrac{\ddots}{\forall y~Rcy\vdash \forall y~\exists x~Rxy}}{\exists x~\forall y~Rxy\vdash \forall y~\exists x~Rxy}{(\exists\mathsf P)}$

Comment: The second existential rule is effectively for that: applied to your case, once show that $\forall y \ R(a,y)$ implies $\forall y \exists x \ R(x,y)$, you can use that second existential rule to conclude that $\exists x \forall y \ R(x,y)$ implies $\forall y \exists x \ R(x,y)$

Answer (score 0):

Your book implements 'existental elimination' as 'existential premise'

$$\dfrac{\mathcal S, \varphi^c_x\vdash \psi}{\mathcal S, \exists x~\varphi\vdash \psi}{(\exists P)}{\small\text{  where $c$ is not free in $\mathcal S, \exists x~\varphi, \psi$ and is a valid substituent for $x$ in $\varphi$}}$$

Which says: When in a certain context, you can derive a conclusion under the assumption of a witness for an existential, you may infer in that context that you can derive that conclusion under the assumption of the existential statement.  (As long as the above caveat is followed.)

You can see it being applied in the examples on page 141.

Thus your proof should end with:

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\vdots}{~~~~~~\forall y~Rcy\vdash \forall y~\exists x~Rxy}}{\exists x~\forall y~Rxy\vdash \forall y~\exists x~Rxy}{(\exists\mathsf P)}$$